# Within excel 2010 how can I convert text formatted number ###### into time formatted as mm:ss.00

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have found other similiar topics on the forum but I am struggling to find a way in excel 2010 to convert text formatted numbers ###### into time formatted as mm:ss.00
Any assistance offered would be really appreciated and it would save me lots of data entry time and data entry errors.
thanks
Nigel

Comment: what is the value of your text formatted numbers?

Comment: Did you try simply setting a time format?

Answer (score 0):

The ###### could simply mean your column widths are too small. Try expanding them and see if that works. Otherwise, you can modify the format (cell data type) by simply right clicking it and selecting "Format cells...". From there, you can select the "Time" format or create your own in the "Custom" format, both located under category.

If you always want the milliseconds to be "00", you may want the custom format `mm:ss:"00"`

Comment: The mm:ss.00 notation indicates to put the decimal fractions of a second, not literally "00".

mm:ss.000 would be to the millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Where your text column begins in A1, and result column begins in B1

Custom formatting for column B, mm:ss.00;@

=TIME(,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-3,2))+TIME(,,RIGHT(A1,2))/100

Comment: Hi Paul,that worked exactly as you said, I learnt something new and it has saved me time, thank you Paul for taking the time to share your knowledge - much appreciated